# Page redirect after beforeunload event incorrect

Tags: javascript, jquery, onbeforeunload

I have a link `logout` which redirects to `login.jsp`. Now, given that my URL is `http://localhost/path1/path2/login.jsp`. After `beforeunload` is fired and clicked `leave page` page redirects to `http://localhost/path1/login.jsp`. I don't understand what happen between the event `beforeunload` and actual page redirect. See my code below

**main.js**

```
$(function(){
 $(window).bind("beforeunload", function(event) {
    if (hasChanges) {
     return "There are modifications, Are you sure?";
    }
 });

 $("#linkLogout").click(function(){
   //do something to backend
   postThis()
   window.location = "login.jsp";
 })
});
```

Also, i also tested a scenario wherien there is no midification, meaning `hasChanges` in the above code is `false`. `window.location` redirects properly.

**NOTE**

1. Please assume that above code is legacy code
2. **This only occurs on Firefox browser**, surprisingly it works on Edge and IE

**UPDATE**

`postThis` performs form.submit() to /path/backend in its definition. If my knowledge is correct, performing form submit() do something with the current page.

Comment: because beforeunload don't work in firefox. use this onbeforeunload

Comment: ohh do you mean `$(window).on("beforeunload",callback)`?

Comment: So your `window.location = "login.jsp"` is redirecting you to `localhost/path1/login.jsp` rather than `localhost/path1/path2/login.jsp` when you already are in the `localhost/path1/path2/login.jsp` page?

Comment: yes that is correct. For example, on other links, it will just be `localhost/path1/path2/otherlink.jsp`. This problem is specific to login link

Comment: sorry i found something in the legacy code, please see update.

Answer (score 0):

try this works for all

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
  var e = e || window.event;

  // For IE and Firefox
  if (e) {
    e.returnValue = 'Any string';
  }

  // For Safari
  return 'Any string';
};
```

refer to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload)

Comment: tried above, redirection still broken, i always end up with `http://localhost/path1/login.jsp` which is a page not found in my case.

Comment: nope the correct link should be `http://localhost/path1/path2/login.jsp`